# Orocommerce configurable Product layout issue

Tags: layout, product, storefront, orocommerce, configurable

I installed the new 5.0 RC Version of Orocommerce and tried to create a configurable Product like I did in the 5.0.0-Beta2 before. The Product itself is working like expected, but the layout of the product in the storefront is wrong.

The configurable part of the product is located outside and over of the actual frame where it normally should be in. (I will upload a picture of it to make it more clear.)

If I create another simple product the product page looks as expected.

[Configurable Product wrong layout - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBMw6.png)

Is this a known problem and is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, blocks out of the box always were rendered after the main product image.
Also I have compared 4.2 and 5.0 the result is similar.

So that looks like there may be a problem at your customization.
Could you provide more information to verify what is affecting it?
Also I wonder to know what blocks (block id in layout) you might have moved.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. My problem was solved by creating a new product family. After that I created a new configurable product based on the new product family and everything worked like expected. Meanwhile we switched to version 5.0.0 LTS and still everything is good. Thanks! Btw. I did no changes on code level. I was using a pretty fresh install with demo data.